# JavaScript: Stack and checking checked boxes and alerting if none checked

Tags: javascript

So, I want to check to see if any checkboxes are checked... if not, alert the user to select them.

I don't want to use jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
function handleChecked() {
  let form = document.getElementById('form');
  var checked_boxes = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++ ) {
    if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox' && form.elements[i].checked == true) {
      checked_boxes=true;      
      handleRemoveElements();
    }  
  }
  if (checked_boxes) {
    handleCheckedBoxes();
  } else { 
    alert("Please select a box.");      
  }
}
```

What ends up happening is I get the alert regardless. I believe this has to do with how the operations are stacked but I can't seem to get it right.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please include the form’s HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `querySelectorAll` with `:checked` and count the total found:

```js
function countTotalCheckboxChecked() {
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.chk1:checked').length);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="chk1" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk1" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk1" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk1" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk1" /><br />
<br />
<button onclick="countTotalCheckboxChecked()">Check</button>
```